# More general traceless normalized matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, matrix-norms

I am wondering about how to characterise the more general traceless matrix over $\Bbb C$

$$ \operatorname{Tr} (T) = 0$$

and having unit Hilbert-Schmidt norm,

$$ \| T \|^2 = \operatorname{Tr} \left( T T^* \right) = 1$$

For a normal matrix with real eigenvalues, it is very intuitive that the eigenvalues are the cosines of a force in a regular poligon,

$$ k_n = \cos ( 2 \pi n / d + \delta)$$ with $d$ the dimension of the matrix. Perhaps in any case I should add the condition that no subset of eigenvalues is traceless, or some other simplicity condition, but that seems to be all. I am no very worried about it because most of my cases of use are 3d matrices.

Now, for complex eigenvalues I expected that it was just multiply times a global phase $e^{i \pi \phi}$. But then I noticed that I can add a whole set of imaginary eigenvalues  $$w_n = i \cos ( 2 \pi n / d + \theta)$$ with a different phase, so that $$k_n \cos \phi + w_n \sin \phi$$ still add to zero and total norm one.  I see this is because

$$\|(T+iQ)\|^2 = \|T\|^2 + \|Q\|^2 + i \operatorname{Tr} \left( Q T^* - T Q^* \right)$$

so if $T$ is self adjoint I can add in this way any other self adjoint operator commuting with it.

So now I am a bit lost about which is the more general form for the eigenvalues if they exist, and of course for the whole matrix. I guess this is a very well known problem, surely I am only lacking vocabulary to search about.

In summary, what I expect is to have some clear characterisation of the matrices and of their eigenvalues. It could be possible to have some general formula for the diagonal case, and then extend via unitary transformation, or proceed via some definition of "simple traceless matrix" so that a general traceless would be a weighted sum of "simple" matrices.

Comment: The condition $\,\def\op{\operatorname} \op{Tr}(TT^+)=\op{rank}(T),\:$ means that $T$ is a **rank-one** matrix, i.e. $\,T=uv^*\:$ The eigenvector is obviously $u$ and the only non-trivial eigenvalue is $\lambda=v^*u.\:$ However, the traceless condition is $\op{Tr}(T) = v^*u = 0,$ so all eigenvalues are equal to zero.

Comment: @greg Sorry my bad, the notation + was supposed to mean conjugate transpose as usual. So Tr(TT*) is just the Hilbert Schmidt norm of T. I am editing.

Comment: Take any nonzero matrix $A$ so that ${\rm Tr}\,A=0.$ Then $T=\|A\|^{-1}A$ is traceless and $\|T\|=1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc good point, but it is more about effective characterisation, for instance up to eigenvalues when they exist.

Comment: Hilbert-Schmidt norm = Frobenius norm?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo not sure in the infinite case. For finite, yes.

Comment: There is a normal matrix with Frobenius norm $1$ and a given spectrum and corresponding set of eigenvectors iff the eigenvectors are orthogonal and $\sum |\lambda|^2$ (summed over the spectrum with multiplicity) is $1$. I don't know what you mean by "cosines of a force in a regular polygon" or "subset of eigenvalues is traceless" or a bunch of other stuff.